# Test Highcharts in pie with Watir

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I am tring to test pie chart in highcharts with watir web driver. I have the issue of locate a tiny small piece of the pie.

```
 #Get the pie 
 series1 = browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-tracker')

 #Get the pieces
 all_path_elements = series1.elements(:css => 'path')
 #get the second to last
 points = all_path_elements[-2..-2]
```

with range -1 to -1 it will able to get the last piece. 
-2 to -2 still last piece.
-3 to -3 will get the third from last.
it will skip the second to last. i think because it is the smallest. but i am able to locate it with my mouse.
is there another way to locate the path elements? so maybe an alternative way can solve my issue.
i made a red dots where the piece gets skip.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDAaH.png

Comment: @justinko sorry justin, i have posted a question for this.

Comment: It would really help if you create a js-fiddle of your exact chart (go to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic and click Edit in jsFiddle). As well, what do you want to do with that small piece of the pie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution myself. instead of hover on to each of the path elements. i did a fire event of the onmouseover of each path elements.

```
 series1 = browser.element(:css => 'g.highcharts-tracker')
 all_path_elements = series1.elements(:css => 'path')
 points = all_path_elements[0..-1]
 point = points.find do |p|  
 p.fire_event "onmouseover"
 puts browser.elements(:css => 'g.highcharts-tooltip tspan')[3].text
 end
```